# Installing the bundle for a MySQL Rail Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I say `bundle install` after some time I get the error:

> Results logged to
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds
>   before bundling.

So I do what it say, I run this command :

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'
```

And then again I run Bundle Install   but again I get the same error.

Where should I begin looking at to fix this issue?

And here is how my GemFile looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'sqlite3'
#START:mysql
group :production do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
#END:mysql

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',    '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails',  '~> 3.2.1'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
#START_HIGHLIGHT
gem 'capistrano'
#END_HIGHLIGHT

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
```

Comment: It looks like you're using both sqlite3 and mysql2 - why aren't you just picking one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for this error could be due to lack of mysql header, so make sure you have installed mysql headers properly.

For Ubuntu/Linux flavor, Use following command to install MySQL client and development package

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

For mac OS:

```
http://www.djangoapp.com/blog/2011/07/24/installation-of-mysql-server-on-mac-os-x-lion/
```

Regards!

Comment: oh so I should actually have MySQL installed on my system..Ok let me try that....on a Mac tho